# Matplotlib error: no attribute '__getitem__' for AxesSubplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, runtime-error

I am trying to make a figure with a number of stacked subplots. I have the data being generated by a different script (data.main), and am trying to loop through my data and plot it. Here is the code:

```
def main(files):
    n=len(files)
    fig, ax= plt.subplots(n,1, sharex=True)
    for i in np.arange(n):
        xdata, ydata, yerr, xerr=data.main(files[i])
        ax[i, 1].plot(xdata,ydata, linestyle='none', marker='o')
        ax[i, 1].errorbar(xdata,ydata,yerr,xerr, linestyle='none')
    plt.show()
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Here you either need to set `squeeze=False`, or you needthe loop to use single indexing, `ax[i].plot(..)`.